# SQL query to fetch count on the association tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write the following SQL Server query, where I also need to fetch the count of `vehicleId` that is being referred in the child table,

```
select 
    BV.[BaseVehicleId], BV.[MakeId], MK.[MakeName], BV.[ModelId], 
    MD.[ModelName], V.[VehicleId], V.[SubModelId], SubMD.[SubModelName], 
    V.[RegionId], V.PublicationStageId,
    V.[LastUpdateDate], V.[InsertDate], V2BedCount, V2BodyCount, 
    V2BrakeCount, V2DriveCount, V2EngineCount,V2MfrCount, V2SpringCount, 
    V2SteeringCount, V2TransmissionCount, V2WheelCount
from  
    [dbo].[BaseVehicle] BV,
    [dbo].[Make] MK,
    [dbo].[Model] MD,
    [dbo].[SubModel] SubMD,
    [dbo].[VehicleToBedConfig] V2Bed,
    [dbo].[VehicleToBodyStyleConfig] V2Body,
    [dbo].[VehicleToBrakeConfig] V2Brake,
    [dbo].[VehicleToDriveType] V2Drive,
    [dbo].[VehicleToEngineConfig] V2Engine,
    [dbo].[VehicleToMfrBodyCode] V2Mfr,
    [dbo].[VehicleToSpringTypeConfig] V2Spring,
    [dbo].[VehicleToSteeringConfig] V2Steering,
    [dbo].[VehicleToTransmission] V2Transmission,
    [dbo].[VehicleToWheelBase] V2Wheel,
    [dbo].[Vehicle] V
where
    V.[PublicationStageId] = '4' 
    and V.[DeleteDate] IS NULL 
    and BV.[BaseVehicleId] = V.[BaseVehicleId] 
    and MK.[MakeId] = BV.[MakeId] 
    and MD.[ModelId] = BV.[ModelId] 
    and V.[SubModelId] = SubMD.[SubModelId] 
    and V.[VehicleId] = V2Bed.[VehicleId] 
    and V.[VehicleId] = V2Body.[VehicleId] 
    and V.[VehicleId] = V2Brake.[VehicleId] 
    and V.[VehicleId] = V2Drive.[VehicleId] 
    and V.[VehicleId] = V2Engine.[VehicleId] 
    and V.[VehicleId] = V2Mfr.[VehicleId] 
    and V.[VehicleId] = V2Spring.[VehicleId] 
    and V.[VehicleId] = V2Steering.[VehicleId] 
    and V.[VehicleId] = V2Transmission.[VehicleId] 
    and V.[VehicleId] = V2Wheel.[VehicleId]
```

I'm looking for a way to push the details on these columns from the above query:

```
V2BedCount, V2BodyCount, V2BrakeCount, 
V2DriveCount, V2EngineCount,
V2MfrCount, V2SpringCount, V2SteeringCount, V2TransmissionCount, 
V2WheelCount
```

Here V2BedCount is the count of Vehicle ID's that are mapped with VehicleToBedConfig table like

```
select COUNT(VehicleId) V2BedCount 
from VehicleToBedConfig 
group by VehicleId
```

Please let me know how do I insert the second query in the first to have one query populate the count details for all these columns

```
V2BedCount, V2BodyCount, V2BrakeCount, 
V2DriveCount, V2EngineCount,
V2MfrCount, V2SpringCount, V2SteeringCount, V2TransmissionCount, 
V2WheelCount
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Id` is a PK in `VehicleToBedConfig` try

```
COUNT(DISTINCT V2Bed.Id) OVER(PARTITION BY V.VehicleId) V2BedCount,
...
```

I advice you use an explicit JOIN syntax.